# Android RunTimeException: Parcel: unable to marshal value

Tags: java, android, serializable, parcel

**NOTE:**

> The code shown below may be a bit hard to read, but i hope it can help. Sorry for that.

I get this error whenever i press HOME button and my app goes background.

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcel: unable to marshal value
>   elektro_fr.newapplication.FragmentsActivity$3@a6c25e4

I'm new to android programming and i would like to create a class which can offer me all the functions without implementing them each time.

I made a My_Activity class:

```
package elektro_fr.my_android;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v4.view.GestureDetectorCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.GestureDetector;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;

public abstract class My_Activity extends AppCompatActivity implements GestureDetector.OnGestureListener, GestureDetector.OnDoubleTapListener{

    private int myLayout;

    protected Bundle mySettings;

    private boolean gesturesEnabled=false;
    private GestureDetectorCompat myGestureDetector;

    private boolean canStart=false;

    private boolean menuEnabled=false;
    private HashMap<String,Action> menuEntries;

    protected List<My_Fragment> fragmentsList=new LinkedList<>();

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        myGestureDetector = new GestureDetectorCompat(this,this);

        if (savedInstanceState==null){

            canStart=true;
        }

        init();
        setContentView(myLayout);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {

        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

        outState.putSerializable("LIST",menuEntries);

        for (int counter=0;counter<fragmentsList.size();counter++){

            getSupportFragmentManager().putFragment(outState,"FRAGMENT_SETTINGS_"+counter,fragmentsList.get(counter));
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {

        super.onStart();
        if (canStart) setGraphics();
        canStart=false;
    }

    protected abstract void init();
    protected abstract void setGraphics();

    @Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);

        if (savedInstanceState!=null){

            menuEntries=(HashMap<String, Action>) savedInstanceState.getSerializable("LIST");
            int size=getSupportFragmentManager().getFragments().size();

            for (int counter=0;counter<size;counter++){

                fragmentsList.add(counter,(My_Fragment)getSupportFragmentManager().getFragment(savedInstanceState,"FRAGMENT_SETTINGS_"+counter));
            }
        }

        refreshState();
    }

    abstract protected void refreshState();

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        return menuEnabled;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

        if (menuEntries.get(item.getTitle())!=null){

            menuEntries.get(item.getTitle()).doAction();
        }

        return menuEnabled;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);

        if (menuEnabled){

            if (menuEntries.size()!=0){

                menu.clear();
                int counter=0;

                for (String s: menuEntries.keySet()){

                    menu.add(Menu.NONE,counter,Menu.NONE,s);
                    counter++;
                }
            }
        }

        return menuEnabled;
    }

    protected void setGestures(boolean enabled){

        gesturesEnabled=enabled;
    }

    protected void setMenu(boolean enabled){

        menuEnabled=enabled;
        menuEntries=new HashMap<>();
    }

    protected HashMap<String, Action> getMenuEntries(){

        return menuEntries;
    }

    public My_Fragment addFragment(Class<? extends My_Fragment> fragmentClass, int fragmentContainer, int fragmentID, Bundle fragmentArgs){

        My_Fragment fragment = null;

        try {

            fragment = fragmentClass.newInstance();

        }
        catch (InstantiationException e){

        }
        catch (IllegalAccessException e){

            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        fragment.setArguments(fragmentArgs);
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(fragmentContainer, fragment).commit();

        fragmentsList.add(fragment);

        return fragment;
    }

    protected My_Fragment getFragment(Class<? extends My_Fragment> fragmentClass){

        for (My_Fragment f: fragmentsList){

            if (fragmentClass.isInstance(f)){

                return f;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    public void removeFragment(My_Fragment fragment,boolean addToBackStack){

        if (fragment.isAdded()){

            FragmentTransaction transaction=getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            if (addToBackStack)transaction.addToBackStack(null);
            transaction.remove(fragment);
            transaction.commit();
            getSupportFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions();
            if (!addToBackStack)fragmentsList.remove(fragment);
        }
    }

    protected void setFullScreen(boolean fullScreen){

        WindowManager.LayoutParams attrs = getWindow().getAttributes();

        if (fullScreen) {

            attrs.flags |= WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
        }
        else {

            attrs.flags &= ~WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
        }

        getWindow().setAttributes(attrs);
    }

    protected void hideActionBar(boolean hidden){

        if (hidden){

            getSupportActionBar().hide();
        }
        else getSupportActionBar().show();
    }

    protected void setLayout(int layoutID){

        myLayout=layoutID;
    }

    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

        if (gesturesEnabled){

            this.myGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
        }

        return true;
    }

    public boolean onSingleTapConfirmed(MotionEvent e) {

        My_AndroidTools.KeyboardTools.closeInputKeyboard(getCurrentFocus());
        return true;
    }

    public boolean onDoubleTap(MotionEvent e) {

        return true;
    }

    public boolean onDoubleTapEvent(MotionEvent e) {

        return true;
    }

    public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {

        return true;
    }

    public void onShowPress(MotionEvent e) {

    }

    public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {

        return true;
    }

    public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float distanceX, float distanceY) {

        return true;
    }

    public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {

    }

    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {

        return false;
    }
}
```

This is FragmentsActivity, which extends and implements My_Activity:

```
package elektro_fr.newapplication;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

import elektro_fr.my_android.Action;
import elektro_fr.my_android.My_Activity;
import elektro_fr.my_android.My_Fragment;
import elektro_fr.newapplication.R;

public class FragmentsActivity extends My_Activity implements My_Fragment.fragmentOperations {

    private MyTopFragment topFragment;
    private MyBottomFragment bottomFragment;

    @Override
    protected void init() {

        setLayout(R.layout.fragments);
        setGestures(true);
        setMenu(true);
    }

    @Override
    protected void setGraphics() {

        Bundle args=new Bundle();
        args.putInt(MyTopFragment.LAYOUT_ID,R.layout.ts_fragment);
        args.putInt(My_Fragment.CENTER_HORIZONTAL,RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);

        topFragment = (MyTopFragment) addFragment(MyTopFragment.class,R.id.MainLayout,R.layout.ts_fragment,args);

        Bundle args2=new Bundle();

        args2.putInt(My_Fragment.LAYOUT_ID,R.layout.bs_fragment);

        args2.putInt(My_Fragment.LAYOUT_WIDTH,RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        args2.putInt(My_Fragment.LAYOUT_HEIGHT,RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

        args2.putInt(My_Fragment.BELOW, R.id.ts);
        args2.putInt(My_Fragment.CENTER_HORIZONTAL,RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);

        bottomFragment = (MyBottomFragment) addFragment(MyBottomFragment.class,R.id.MainLayout,R.layout.bs_fragment,args2);

        getMenuEntries().put("Menu Item #1", new Action() {

            @Override
            public void doAction() {

                Log.i("Ciccio","you pressed 1");
            }
        });

        getMenuEntries().put("Menu Item #2", new Action() {

            @Override
            public void doAction() {

                Log.i("Ciccio","you pressed 2");
            }
        });

        getMenuEntries().put("Menu Item #3", new Action() {
            @Override
            public void doAction() {

                Log.i("Ciccio","you pressed 3");
            }
        });
    }

    protected void refreshState(){

        topFragment = (MyTopFragment) getFragment(MyTopFragment.class);
        bottomFragment = (MyBottomFragment) getFragment(MyBottomFragment.class);
    }

    @Override
    public void ClickButtonOperation(Object[] arguments) {

        switch((Integer)arguments[0]){

            case 0:

                bottomFragment.setText((String)arguments[1],(String)arguments[2]);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

This is My_Fragment class:

```
package elektro_fr.my_android;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.text.Layout;
import android.util.Log;
import android.util.TypedValue;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

public abstract class My_Fragment extends Fragment {

    public final static String LAYOUT_ID="layout_id";
    public final static String LAYOUT_WIDTH="layout_width";
    public final static String LAYOUT_HEIGHT="layout_height";

    public final static String BELOW="layout_below";
    public final static String ABOVE="layout_above";

    public final static String ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM="align_parent_bottom";
    public final static String CENTER_HORIZONTAL="center_horizontal";

    private String[] params={

            LAYOUT_ID,LAYOUT_WIDTH, LAYOUT_HEIGHT, ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM, CENTER_HORIZONTAL, BELOW, ABOVE
    };

    protected int fragmentLayout;

    protected fragmentOperations myActivity;
    protected Bundle mySettings;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        if (savedInstanceState!=null){

            mySettings=new Bundle();
            mySettings.putAll(savedInstanceState);
        }
        else mySettings=getArguments();
        fragmentLayout=mySettings.getInt(LAYOUT_ID);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        if (savedInstanceState != null) {

            mySettings.putAll(savedInstanceState);
            refreshState();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {

        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

        setState();
        outState.putAll(mySettings);
    }

    public interface fragmentOperations{

        void ClickButtonOperation(Object[] arguments);
    }

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view=inflater.inflate(fragmentLayout,container,false);

        int widthSettings=mySettings.getInt(params[1]);
        int heightSettings=mySettings.getInt(params[2]);

        view.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams((widthSettings==0?RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT:widthSettings),(heightSettings==0?RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT:heightSettings)));

        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutConfig= (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams();

        for (int counter=3;counter<params.length;counter++){

            int settings=mySettings.getInt(params[counter]);

            if (settings!=0){

                if (counter==5){

                    layoutConfig.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW,settings);
                }
                else if (counter==6){

                    layoutConfig.addRule(RelativeLayout.ABOVE,settings);
                }
                else{

                    layoutConfig.addRule(settings);
                }
            }
        }

        init(view);

        return view;
    }

    protected abstract void init(View v);
    protected abstract void setState();
    protected abstract void refreshState();

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {

        super.onAttach(context);
        myActivity=(fragmentOperations)getActivity();
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**

Finally, Action (interface), which i edited in order to implement Serializable:

```
package elektro_fr.my_android;

import java.io.Serializable;

public interface Action extends Serializable{

    public void doAction();
}
```

This is the error:

> Process: elektro_fr.newapplication, PID: 24970
>                                                                              java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcelable encountered IOException writing serializable object (name = elektro_fr.newapplication.FragmentsActivity$3)

Caused by:

> Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: elektro_fr.newapplication.FragmentsActivity

why should i implement serializable in this class?

Comment: StackOverflow doesn't work like a classic forum, it's a Q&A site. Please edit the question and remove the _(solved)_ from the title and also the solution. Add the solution using the _Answer Your Question_ button below. And for the future keep in mind to post only the minimal amount of code necessary to trigger the problem.

Comment: @perissf Thank you for saying it. I edited my post. Unfortunately, i didn't know where the problem could be, so i thought giving the whole code would have been a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

You try to save menuEntries in OnSaveInstanceState, but the type is HashMap and this type is not serializable. Only primitive can be save or custom object when your implement the serialization yourself.

Comment: And is "Action" serializable ?

Comment: Added "implements Serializable" to "Action". The error has changed: see post for edits.

Comment: Ok I understand your code. You can't do that. When you serialize an object, only the fields are serialized and save. But here you try to serialize the doAction() method... You need to change the Action object. Maybe you can just save the item position on your HashMap or create an object and store your information in the fields.

Comment: I think you are right, but i thought that setting Action class Serializable, the objects created would have been serialized without any problem, even if they don't have any fields.

Can you please explain better what should i do? Thanks

Comment: Yes you can serialize an object without any fields, but it's not a good practice and you can have errors... Depending on what you need, you must save in bundle values and not methods. In your exemple, you need only the item id or the item position, so you can change your HashMap with `new HashMap<String, int>` and get the int to make your action.

Comment: and how can i retrieve the respective actions, which differ from one position to an other, if i can't save Action objects?

Comment: You can create a method in your activity or fragment like `void makeAction(int action) { if(action == 1) { //action for 1.. } else if(action == 2) { //.... }`

Answer (score 0):

**SOLUTION:**

Following Johann67 idea:

> Ok I understand your code. You can't do that. When you serialize an
>   object, only the fields are serialized and save. But here you try to
>   serialize the doAction() method... You need to change the Action
>   object. Maybe you can just save the item position on your HashMap or
>   create an object and store your information in the fields.

So I modified my code.

First of all Ichanged my menuEntries object to a List of String.

Second, i created a new method:

```
protected void dispatchItemAction(int itemID);
```

which can be overridden in order to switch between actions to do, based on the itemID.

And i modified this method:

```
   @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

        dispatchItemAction(item.getItemId());

        return menuEnabled;
    }

    protected void dispatchItemAction(int itemID){


    }
```

now, to add menu items:

```
protected void addMenuItems(){

    getMenuEntries().add("Menu Item #1");
    getMenuEntries().add("Menu Item #2");
    getMenuEntries().add("Menu Item #3");
}

@Override
protected void dispatchItemAction(int itemID) {

    switch(itemID){

        case 0:

            Log.i("Log","Pressed #1.");
        break;

        case 1:

            Log.i("Log","Pressed #2.");
        break;

        case 2:

            Log.i("Log","Pressed #3.");
        break;
    }
}
```